# How do you attack a specific player in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I want to play against my friend in Clash of Clans. Is there a way to attack a specific player by username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way you can attack a specific player. The only way you could make it likely to happen is if both of you are ranked extremely high on the leader board, as fewer people will have similar trophy count to you, making it more likely for you to find them while searching for bases.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this feature isn't available at the moment but I hope it's added soon. I think Supercell is currently focusing on their latest game, Clash Royale, so it will be a while until its added.